# How to monitor API calls made by an Android App?

Tags: adb

I am using an Android Virtual Device and I am running the Monkey Runner script to generate user input. Now, I have to see the API calls made by that app. Is there any tool or script that will help me? I've tried Strace, but it does not keep a track of API instead it keeps trace of System calls.

Comment: This question was closed because it's a bit unclear what does "API calls" mean; is it Android system API, 3rd-party internet-based API, or both?

Answer (score 0):

The XPosed framework allows to hook and therefore monitor every App and Android method. Therefore it can be used for creating a log of certain API methods.

However this require to hook every API method you are interested in.

I found two open source projects aiming in what you want. Both are implemented as an XPosed module:

1. [Droidmon](https://github.com/idanr1986/droidmon) (last change in 2016)
2. [Sensitive_API_Monitor](https://github.com/cyruliu/Sensitive_API_Monitor)

You may have to expend those projects if APIs you are interested in are not hooked by those projects.

Comment: For these to work I'll have to manually provide the details of the methods for API I am looking for, which is not possible as I don't know all the APIs that can be used.

Comment: All the APIs are listed [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html).  However it does not make sense to track them all. May be you should edit your question and exactly describe what and why you want to track. If you don't event know what you want to track I think there is no solution for you. First you have to know what you want...

Comment: My main intention of the project is to classify an android app as malicious or not. So for that I'll be using API calls made by that during runtime. So, I have to extract all the API calls made by that app including REST API, third party API

Comment: AFAIR there is no REST API in Android. And detecting libraries included in an Android app becomes nearly impossible if the app is heavily obfuscated.